# Unable to pass parameters from maven command to Testng Runner

Tags: java, maven, testng

My Testng Runner

```
@Parameters("exeenv")
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(ITestContext context, String exeenv) {

 System.out.println("Testng Value before class=> " + exeenv);
}


@Parameters({
 "exeenv"
})
@Test
public void run(String exeenv) {
 System.out.println("Testng value at run " + exeenv);
 super.run();
}
```

My POM :

```
<build>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
      <configuration>
         <parallel>classes</parallel>
         <threadCount>3</threadCount>
         <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
         <systemPropertyVariables>
            <testconfig>${testconfig}</testconfig>
            <exeenv>${exeenv}</exeenv>
            <browser>${browser}</browser>
            <uitest>${uitest}</uitest>
         </systemPropertyVariables>
         <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         </suiteXmlFiles>
         <!-- <includes>
            <include>**/ExecutionRunner.java</include>
            </includes> -->
      </configuration>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <goals>
               <goal>integration-test</goal>
               <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
</build>
```

My Command:

`mvn clean verify -Dexeenv=dev`

My Output:

```
Testng Value before class=> QA
Testng value at run=> QA
```

I am passing the exeenv value as dev in maven command but I always see only QA in the output. Could somebody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

There are mainly two ways through which we can provide parameter values to testng tests.

Through testng.xml XML configuration file and 
Through DataProviders

You might want to try `System.getProperty` for reading envs from command line

Comment: Thank you, I used the System.getProperty to read from command line and if no value is passed then I use the variable to the Testng File.